# Powermockito unable to mock the super call

Tags: junit, mockito

So basically I'm trying to write a Junit using powermockito for a adapter for a service class which consumes a webservice.

I have an adapter with a constructor that inturn creates a new service object in it's own constructor by calling a super class. I have to test my adapter. I have used power mockito to mock my adapter as well as my service class but I don't think the mocked object is able to perform the super call. The following is the structure of my code. I want the super class to return my mocked object upon call.

```
public class CommonPoolingServiceAdp {

    private CPSSecurity cpsServicePort;

    public CommonPoolingServiceAdp() {      
        CommonPoolingService service= new CommonPoolingService();
        cpsServicePort=service.getCommonPoolingServicePort();
    }

    public SercurityDataResponse getBroadcastElements(broadcastReqObj)
    {
        SercurityDataResponse=null;
        response=cpsServicePort.getBroadcastElements(broadcaseRequestObj);
    }
} 

public class CommonPoolingService extends Service {

    {
    static
    {
        //few mandatory initializations
    }

    public CommonPoolingService()
    {
        super(WSDL_Location,QName);
    }

    public CSPSecurity getCommonPoolingServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(QName);
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post you current test code. So you want the call `super.getPort(QName)` to return a mock `CSPSecurity`?

Answer (score 0):

Please share a bit more of your code. By the way, this is how you mock a super class method :

```
public class SuperClass {

 public void method() {
      methodA(); // I don't want to run this!
 }
}
public class MyClass extends SuperClass{
public void method(){
    super.method()
    methodB(); // I only want to test this!
}
}

@Test
public void testMethod() {
MyClass spy = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());

// Prevent/stub logic in super.method()
Mockito.doNothing().when((SuperClass)spy).methodA();

// When
spy.method();

// Then
verify(spy).methodB();
}
```

Hope, it will help.